# django queryset runtime - get nth entry in constant time

Tags: python, django, runtime, big-o, django-queryset

I'm using multiple ways to get data from db via different django querysets,
but I would like to know the runtime for each queryset and if possible a better way (to maybe get data in constant time!!)

```
qs = MyModel.objects.order_by('-time')
qs = qs.filter(blah = blah)
```

to get the first entry I'm doing this:

```
entry = list(qs[:1])
first_entry = entry[0]
```

or to get 10th and last entry:

```
entry = list(qs)
some_entry = entry[9]
last_entry = entry[-1]
```

but I believe this will take O(n) time, is there anyway to get the nth term in constant time?
I dont want to use get() as I dont know the id or other value of the entry(its sorted), but only the position.

I may also use annotate, but this also take O(n) runtime.

```
MyModel.objects.values('date').annotate(min_value=Min('value')).order_by('min_value')[0]
```

*I know the position just need that entry in constant time?*

Comment: I don't really think big O is a useful metric here. As Peter points out, using slicing pushes the work onto the database, but a LIMIT/OFFSET query will presumably still do some linear-time work to find the right starting point in the index - it's just that that work is highly optimised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> Use a subset of Python’s array-slicing syntax to limit your QuerySet to a certain number of results. This is the equivalent of SQL’s LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.
>
> Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query. An exception is if you use the “step” parameter of Python slice syntax.
>
> To retrieve a single object rather than a list (e.g. SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 1), use a simple index instead of a slice.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

The part about not evaluating the queryset as you slice it is the important part.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I saw this document before but I guess I didn't understood! so when we doing `Entry.objects.all()[0]` this will just hit the db ones and not on all entries?

Comment: Yeah, that should turn it into a limited queryset that tells the DB it only needs a single value when you evaluate it.  If you're unsure, you can look at the exact queries being performed through various methods - I found the Django toolbar package useful: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar