# How to get the nth record of a model with Python - Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm currently working on a command that deletes old records for some models that grow a lot in the database. The idea behind is receiving a parameter that indicates from which record number (not id) we have to delete backwards. For doing this i came up with this solution:

```
reference_record = WarmUpCache.objects.filter(company_id=company).values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('-id')[_number_of_records]
records_to_delete = WarmUpCache.objects.filter(company_id=company,id__lt=reference_record)
if records_to_delete:
   records_to_delete.delete()
```

For example, for a given company_id=118 I get the ids of the records associated to that Company. Having this, I try to get the **n**Th record and then, calculate how many records are with an id lower than the given one. After that, delete all of them.

Currently this solution is working, but I'm managing to improve it somehow. I have checked stackoverflow to find any answers but I only found old answers that explain almost the same solution I made:

[django query get last n records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555673/django-query-get-last-n-records)

[django queryset runtime - get nth entry in constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554322/django-queryset-runtime-get-nth-entry-in-constant-time)

So, the question itself is ¿Is there any way to improve this query by obtaining just the nth record of a model?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python slice to get a range of items starting from Nth and then delete like so:

```
WarmUpCache.objects.order_by('id')[from_which_to_delete:].delete()
```

also this condition

```
if records_to_delete:
   records_to_delete.delete()
```

is not required cause if `records_to_delete` is empty - `.delete()` will just do nothing.

Comment: Hello, Alex:
I would say that I have maybe explained myseld poorly:
It's not that I need to delete from a specific position within the array of elements. What I really need is to delete from an specific id backwards but I only receive is the number of elements (the older ones) I have to delete.